# HTML/CSS: Div 100% height of page

Tags: html, css

How do I get the div (the blue box) to fill out the whole page? I have the body tag set to `height:100%`, but this doesn't seem to matter.

See http://jsfiddle.net/rVyrX/1/

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
body,html
{
   height:100%;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every containing element must have it's height set to 100% along with the element that you want sized to 100%. This assumes that the target element (here, the blue box div) is not positioned absolutely, in which case you can simply set both its "top" and "bottom" values to zero.